# How to insert a node at specific position in dagred3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3

I am trying to create a simple graph and i wanted to add nodes at specific position.

```
const graph = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({})
    .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function () {
      return {}
    })
graph.setNode('a', {label: 'a', height: 20, width: 40})
```

The setNode is creating a node, is there anyway that i can specify the position?

Comment: hi Sam, Do you know how to delete a existing edge or update it in d3 graph?

Comment: https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3/issues/64

Comment: @MontyTomar graph.removeEdge(v, w) should work.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie i couldnt find any solution over there. can you please send that code?

Comment: The github issue implies fixing nodes is not currently a feature?